# Why does my schema.rb file not reflect what the database is

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

Inside my schema.rb file is the following:

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "username"
    t.integer  "character_code"
    t.string   "league"
    t.integer  "wins"
    t.integer  "losses"
    t.string   "password"
  end
```

but I keep getting errors when I try to view the new users page that says:

```
undefined method `username' for #<User id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

and when I try and initialize an instance of User in the console and set any of the attributes it says they don't exist. Any ideas?

Comment: Please show us the output from your database console showing what is actually in these tables. `describe users` on MySQL or `\d+ users` on Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using ActiveRecord migrations.

Have you run them with `rake db:migrate` ?